# Can my app deploy a app that uploaded by a user?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

I am doing my course project, and I am the only one choose GAE. Now, I just don't know how to satisfy a requirement in this course project.

My app is a homework submittal system allows students upload their homework. I can implement almost everything using GAE. But, you know, **what students uploaded is web app too, and requirement says my app should allow users upload their app, and my app can deploy their apps and give the teacher URLs to check.**

I really don't know how to implement this. Can anyone explain how can this happen?

And if there is a way to do this. what kind of file should a user upload, war?
BTW. assuming the users upload a google appEngine app written in Python.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't know definitely whether what you describe is possible or not, but I can tell you that it would amount to an extremely sophisticated application, one that would take a great deal of time and programmer effort to bring to fruition. You really might want to consider whether or not this is the best project for a university course. Uploading and delivering HTML and CSS files (which I think is what you've been talking about in your questions to date) is one thing, but providing a system to automatically create and manage AppEngin apps from and AppEngin app is quite another. Rethink this.

Comment: @AdamCrossland Thank you. It really confused me and I just have not enough knowledge to help me make the decision. Now, I decide to let users deploy their app by themselves and submit the URL. :)

Comment: I think that is a wise decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's technically possible, but the App Engine Terms of Service prohibit applications that upload other applications.